# SpringBootApplication Mapping With Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot but understand how Spring framework works.
I am unable to understand how SpringBootApplication class maps/call other controller.Can anyone explain how the internal mapping works?

Is there any other guide available with explanation other than Spring Guide site?

I tried few examples and really liked how easy they were but really want to understand the complete flow instead of just annotating classes.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` isn't a controller, it's just a configuration class that kicks off component scanning in its own package. All controller mappings follow ordinary Spring MVC rules.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis. Also, Are there any references or guides to understand the flow?

Comment: See the [DispatcherServlet section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet) of Spring Framework's documentation

Comment: SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan annotation. You can find more information on http://parmodarora.com/2016/01/06/springbootapplication-annotation/